# I want to set the code .tostring but it isn't available

Tags: java, android

In the line of code marked by comment I want to put townHallLvl but it needs to be string so i tried to use .toString but it wasn't available.
Is there another solution or I made something wrong.

```
package com.example.android.planmyclash;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//set buildings' values
int townHallLvl = 1;

//declare ids
TextView townHallText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.town_hall_lvl);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setValues();

}

public void setValues(){
    townHallText.setText();             //this line <----
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it wasn't available"? What exactly did you try, and what happened? What are you trying to call `toString` on?

Comment: Use `townHallText.setText(String.valueOf(townHallLvl)); ` in order to convert the integer to a String. `setText()` requires a `String` or a String resource ID as an argument.

Comment: Thanks man. I think you should make it as answer instead of comment

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG use it in answers section and users will see it quickly

Comment: Yes man he is right!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
townHallText.setText(String.valueOf(townHallLvl));
```

in order to convert the integer to a String.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
townHallText.setText(townHallLvl+"");
```

I hope it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.android.planmyclash;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//set buildings' values
int townHallLvl = 1;
TextView townHallText;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//declare ids
townHallText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.town_hall_lvl);
setValues();

}

public void setValues(){
townHallText.setText(townHallLvl + "");             //this line <----
}

}
```

***Happy Coding***